# Meteor: Elements from CollectionA re-rendering when I insert to CollectionB

Tags: dom, callback, rendering, jquery-animate, meteor

I'm attempting to fade-in new elements in a reactive {{#each}} of the comments posted by users.

I have a code sample at https://gist.github.com/3119147 of a very simple comments section (textarea and new comment insert code not included, but it's very boilerplate.).  Included is a snippet of CSS where I give `.comment.fresh { opacity: 0; }`, and then in my script, I have:

```
Template.individual_comment.postedago_str = function() {
  var id = this._id;
  Meteor.defer(function() {
    $('#commentid_'+id+'.fresh').animate({'opacity':'1'}, function() {
      $(this).removeClass('fresh');
    });
  });
  return new Date(this.time).toString();
};
```

Which seems like a terrible place to execute an animation.  My thinking is that each time a new comment is rendered, it will need to call all my `Template.individual_comment.*` functions, so that's why my animation defers from one of those.  However, Meteor is calling `Template.individual_comment.postedago_str()` each time a *different* collection (Likes) is inserted to.  This means I click the Like button, and my whole list of comments flashes white and fades back in (very annoying!).

I read the Meteor documentation and tried to figure out how to better slice up my templates so only chunks will update, and I added id="" attributes everywhere that seemed reasonable.. still this bug.  Anyone know what's going on?

TIA!

Comment: Hi Mike, can you reduce your gist down further so that only the core elements involved in the problem are there? That would help.

Comment: @TomColeman: But you need the other lines to be able to reproduce the problem, right? Perhaps he could set up a debug version online or so with minimal code (which we can inspect as it's in debug mode).

Comment: Well there are a lot of elements in that template that potentially could be impacting. It would be easier to reason about with a reduction to the simplest possible example that exhibits the same behaviour.

Comment: I'll put together a barebones demo later today Tom.  However there's really not much there... two collections, a little HTML, and a few template helpers in the JS.  Just trying to demonstrate that the Template.interaction stuff seems to be messing with the Template.individual_comment stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, you could wrap an `{{if}}` block around the `fresh` class on individual comments, that would check the comment's creation time and only add the `fresh` class in the first place if the comment is actually recent. Something like:

```
<div class="comment{{#if isActuallyFresh}} fresh{{/if}}" id="commentid_{{_id}}">
```

And then define the isActuallyFresh function:

```
Template.individual_comment.isActuallyFresh = function() {
  if ((new Date().getTime() - this.time) < 300000) // less than 5 minutes old
     return true;
  else
     return false;
```

Comment: Sorry I never saw this answer!  This is a great idea and probably would have worked, but I retired the project I was working on.  I'll definitely try this approach next time!